# How to set and get session in Django?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-forms, django-sessions

I need to set a variable on session, when a user login happens. How can I do this?

```
if request.user.is_authenticated():
    profile = request.user.get_profile()
    request.session['idempresa'] = profile.idempresa
```

My other question is in a form:

```
class PedidoItensForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = ItensPedido

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        profile = kwargs.pop('vUserProfile', None)
        super(PedidoItensForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

How can I get the "idempresa" value of session, to use in my queryset?

Comment: Edit: this line: profile = kwargs.pop('vUserProfile', None)  doesn`t work... I cannot know how to pass vUserProfile when I use inlineformset_factory, if  I get how to pass vUserProfile using inlineformset_factory, this problem is solved!

Comment: 1: Build your own middleware. Or put it wherever authentication happens.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/middleware/


2: Ask new questions in a new question.

Answer (score 102):

For setting session variable:

```
request.session['idempresa'] = profile.idempresa
```

For getting session Data:

```
if 'idempresa' in request.session:
    idempresa = request.session['idempresa']
```

Comment: @slavugan Django sessions don't have a save() method. They are saved automatically when changed, or you can force a save by setting `request.session.modified` to `True`.

Comment: You can use session in templates like this `{{ request.session.idempresa }}`

Answer (score 65):

For setting session variable:

```
request.session['fav_color'] = 'blue'
```

For getting session Data

```
fav_color = request.session.get('fav_color', 'red')
```

Reference: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/sessions/

Answer (score 2):

You can set and get session with `request.session['key']` and get session with [request.session.get('key')](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/http/sessions/#django.contrib.sessions.backends.base.SessionBase.get) in Djanog Views as shown below. *`request.session.get()` returns `None` by default if the key doesn't exist and you can change `None` to other value like `Doesn't exist` by setting it to the 2nd argument as shown below and you can see [When sessions are saved](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/http/sessions/#when-sessions-are-saved) and you can see [my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76631780/why-is-session-unexpectedly-saved-in-django/76641365#76641365) and [my answer](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/settings/#session-save-every-request) explaining when and where session is saved:

```py
# "views.py"

from django.shortcuts import render

def test(request):
    request.session['person'] = {'name':'John','age':27}
    print(request.session['person']) # {'name':'John','age':27}
    print(request.session['person']['name']) # John
    print(request.session['person']['age']) # 27
    print(request.session.get('person')) # {'name':'John','age':27}
    print(request.session.get('person')['name']) # John
    print(request.session.get('person')['age']) # 27
    print(request.session.get('animal')) # None
    print(request.session.get('animal', "Doesn't exist")) # Doesn't exist
    return render(request, 'index.html', {})
```

And, you can get session with `request.session.key` in Django Templates as shown below:

```html
# "templates/index.html"

{{ request.session.person }}      {# {'name':'John','age':27} #}
{{ request.session.person.name }} {# John #}
{{ request.session.person.age }}  {# 27 #}
```

And, you can delete session with the code below. *[request.session.pop('key')](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/http/sessions/#django.contrib.sessions.backends.base.SessionBase.pop) can get, then delete session and error occurs if the key doesn't exist and the 2nd argument is not set and if the key doesn't exist and the 2nd argument is set, the 2nd argument is returned and [request.session.clear()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/http/sessions/#django.contrib.sessions.backends.base.SessionBase.clear) and [request.session.flush()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/http/sessions/#django.contrib.sessions.backends.base.SessionBase.flush) can delete all the current session and you can see [my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76644005/request-session-clear-vs-request-session-flush-in-django) and [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76644005/request-session-clear-vs-request-session-flush-in-django#answer-76644164) explaining the difference between `request.session.clear()` and `request.session.flush()`:

```py
# "views.py"

from django.shortcuts import render

def test(request):
    del request.session['person']
    del request.session['person']['name']
    del request.session['person']['age']
    print(request.session.pop('person')) # {'name':'John','age':27}
    print(request.session.pop('animal') # Error
    print(request.session.pop('animal', "Doesn't exist")) # Doesn't exist
    request.session.clear()
    request.session.flush()
    return render(request, 'index.html', {})
```