# Setting a default value in session if key does not exist

Tags: django, session

I would like to obtain a value from the session and in case that value does not exist I would like to supply a default one. I got my current approach from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14465993/how-can-i-set-and-get-session-variable-in-django). This is what I am doing

```
fav_color = request.session.get('fav_color', 'red')
```

The above works fine however I noticed that if the key variable is placed in settings.py then the output is None.Which I would like to fix. For instance this is in my settings.py

```
VARIABLE_PATIENT_ID_DEFINE="patientID"
```

Now in some other app I am using it like this

```
    t = "somevar"
    s = settings.VARIABLE_PATIENT_ID_DEFINE
    print(s) # prints patientID
    fav_color = request.session.get(s, 'red') --->After this line Default is None
    fav_color = request.session.get(t, 'red') --->After this line Default is red
```

My questions is why does

```
fav_color = request.session.get(s, 'red')
```

fail and return none ? Why does assigning from `settings.VARIABLE_PATIENT_ID_DEFINE` cause an issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `request.session` already contain `{"patientID": None}`
then performing `request.session.get("patientID", "red")` will also return `None` since this is the value of `patientID` key.

you would only get `"red"` if the key doesn't exist at all in the session which doesn't seem to be the case here.

you can solve your problem by writing

`fav_color = request.session.get(s, 'red') or 'red'`

Comment: the session does not contain a key called patientID why is it returning none when it should be returning red. it returns red in the second case but not in the first case. it shld be returning red in both cases

Comment: can you `print dict(request.session)` ? what is the output?
pretty sure you will find it there

Comment: yes its in there. Thanks for clearing that up. Could you tell me what dict(request.session) does ? I already thought request.session is a dictionary what does dict(request.session) do ?

Comment: session attribute is a dictionary-like object. It behave like dictionary but has some extra functions and properties. `dict(request.session)` convert the session into normal python dictionary.
You shouldn't need to do that when using the session. I just suggested to use it for debugging purpose

Comment: yes i know but i like the approach. Thanks for clearing this up