# Saving form data from a FormView to session

Tags: django, session-variables, django-class-based-views

I am trying to capture the POST request data for each field and store it in the session so that I can use the data in another view. But I am getting errors in the other view because the session variables are returning 'None'.

Before, I had written the code using a non-class based view and fetched the values with `request.POST.get('name')` and this worked. What should I be doing here?

```
class TripsView(FormView):
    """ A view to show all trips and receive trip search data """

    template_name = "products/trips.html"
     form_class = SearchTripsForm

    def form_valid(self, form):
        """
        Takes the POST data from the SearchTripsForm and stores it in the session
        """

        trip_choice = form.cleaned_data["destination"].id
        self.request.session["destination_choice"] = trip_choice
        self.request.session["searched_date"] = "26-12-2021"
        self.request.session["passenger_total"] = form.cleaned_data[
        "passengers"
        ]
        return super(TripsView, self).form_valid(form)

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        """ Adds to the context the Product objects categorized as trips """

        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context["destinations"] = Product.objects.filter(category=3)
        return context

    def get_success_url(self):
        """ Overides the success url when the view is run """

        return reverse("selection")
```

My other view is as follows:

```
class SelectTripView(View):
    """
    Provides the user a set of choice options based on their search input in
    products.TripsView
    """

    template_name = "bookings/trips_available.html"
    form_class = DateChoiceForm

    def get(self, request):
        """
        Initialises the DateChoiceForm with data from SearchTripsForm
        & render to the template
        """

        searched_date = self.request.session["searched_date"]
        print(searched_date)
        naive_searched_date = datetime.strptime(searched_date, "%Y-%m-%d")
        gte_dates = self.trips_matched_or_post_date(searched_date)
        lt_dates = self.trips_preceding_date(searched_date)
    
        ... etc etc...
```

The code flags an error here at the `datetime.strptime()` method because it says argument 1 must be a string not a tuple - (None)

**Update:*** I have located that the problem is because the date string is being converted to a tuple (2,0,2,1 etc..) - maybe because it includes punctuation dashes '-' between Y-M-D? Is there a workaround for this? That being said, the string was just a placeholder. In the real case, I am pulling the value from form data which gives me date object and would need to be serialized before sending to the session.

I am confused as to why using request.POST.get() to retrieve the form data in non classed based View did not encounter such errors. Is there a difference to the data once it is cleaned_data?

Comment: I would inspect the object `self.request.session` to see what keys it might have. Sidenote: I don't think your strptime will work: '26-12-2021' does not match format '%Y-%m-%d'. [possible solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14465993/how-can-i-set-and-get-session-variable-in-django)

Comment: Good point but unfortunately that doesn;t stop the error. I put a print statement just after where I set the keys in the session but it doesn't print anything so to me that says it's empty...?

Comment: What does inspect tells you about the session right before ```return super(TripsView, self).form_valid(form)``` in ```TripsView```?
I guess ```self.request.session.modified = True``` will not solve it?