# Session is not working in django restviews

Tags: python, django, django-sessions

Hi i am trying to set a value in session but not getting the value, I don't know what I am doing wrong.

Setting Value

```
class ClView(GenericAPIView):

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        # Get Method Code
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        cid = request.data['id'] 
        self.request.session['myid'] = cid
        request.session.modified = True
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_202_ACCEPTED)
```

Getting Value

```
class MainView(APIView):
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        cid = self.request.session.get('myid')
        return Response({"id":cid})
```

`'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',` in the middlewares
and already tried without `'self'`

Comment: I think there's an inherent problem with Django2 and session usage with the rest framework. The values supported in SESSION_COOKIE_SAMESITE for Django2 are not complete. Django 3 and Django 4 have resolved these issues. I would suggest upgrading to Django3 or Django 4

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see, you are getting and setting the request session with the correct syntax.

e.g.

```
request.session.get('KEY') # for get
request.session['KEY'] = 1 # for set
```

[Here's another related post about getting/setting items in the cache.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14465993/how-can-i-set-and-get-session-variable-in-django)

It's difficult to say what your failure is with the given information.

I have a couple questions about your setup that could maybe help clarify for others to help answer your issue.

- Are you using a database-backed session? If so, have you made sure to run migrate?
- Are you running a cache with a cache-backed session?
- Are you setting `SESSION_COOKIE_AGE` to a very low value?

Comment: answer is no to all of your questions. Is there any other way rather then using session

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking here. Your original post is asking about why your session is not working to get/set items from the session.

Comment: Concerning no to all of the questions, what have you set `SESSION_ENGINE` to currently? By default it is set to the database.

Answer (score -1):

You were setting the `self.request.session`, instead you needed to set the `request.session`.

```py
class ClView(GenericAPIView):

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        # Get Method Code
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        cid = request.data['id'] 
        request.session['myid'] = cid
        request.session.modified = True
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_202_ACCEPTED)
```

```
class MainView(APIView):
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        cid = request.session.get('myid')
        return Response({"id":cid})
```