# Django: How to ask user to select an option on website homepage and use that value in all website pages

Tags: python, django

I am working on a website, I am confused with following.

I need to ask user on homepage to select an value from a dropdown and use that value in other pages of website. I have an Navbar on base.html which is common on all other view files via - {% extends '..base/html' %}, so nav bar will be common and below it all other pages render.

So I am thinking to have a dropdown on navbar and every page I open should be able to keep the selected dropdown value at start, unless it is changed.

Eg: ecommerce sites asks for PINCODE and uses that to show available products. (Similar to this).

How should I solve this, I am really confused and not able to find anything.

Thanks.

Comment: Hope this helps. :)
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14465993/how-can-i-set-and-get-session-variable-in-django

Comment: @AbhayKatheria Thanks using session solved my requirement.