# request.session.clear() vs request.session.flush() in Django

Tags: python, django, logout, difference, django-sessions

I tried both [request.session.clear()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/http/sessions/#django.contrib.sessions.backends.base.SessionBase.clear) and [request.session.flush()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/http/sessions/#django.contrib.sessions.backends.base.SessionBase.flush) and they deleted all session data and logged a user out.

Actually, there is the explanation for `request.session.flush()` as shown below while there isn't for `request.session.clear()`:

> Deletes the current session data from the session and deletes the session cookie. This is used if you want to ensure that the previous session data can’t be accessed again from the user’s browser (for example, the django.contrib.auth.logout() function calls it).

My questions:

1. What is the difference between `request.session.clear()` and `request.session.flush()`?
2. Which should I use basically?

Answer (score 1):

The documentation is indeed very unclear on this point, it is quite remarkable that these methods are not documented.

When we look at the source code however, then we see that `.flush()` does more than `.clear()`. Indeed if we look at the [source code <sup>[GitHub]</sup>](https://github.com/django/django/blob/2584783f46922bcb456ceb9700a3726314df65d3/django/contrib/sessions/backends/base.py#L289-L296):

> ```
> def flush(self):
>     """
>     Remove the current session data from the database and regenerate the
>     key.
>     """
>     self.clear()
>     self.delete()
>     self._session_key = None
> ```

[**`.flush()`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/http/sessions/#django.contrib.sessions.backends.base.SessionBase.flush) does more, it also deletes the `sessions` record (that is not the case for `.clear()` which "empties" the dictionary, but the record still exists), and sets the `._session_key` to `None` so it will regenerate a new session key.

[**`.clear()`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/http/sessions/#django.contrib.sessions.backends.base.SessionBase.clear) on the other hand only removes the *items* attached to this session. This thus means that the session key remains the same, that the `Session` *record* is not removed (but will then only have an empty dictionary as data).

But both will indeed basically "log out" the user, since the session normally stores the user id of the logged in user, and thus in the next request, it will use the same session, but can no longer link it to any data, hence there is no user linked to the request.